# JQuery onclick select this with another class

Tags: jquery, class, this

I have a code like this:

```
$(".um").click(function () {
    $(".subconteudo.dois").slideUp();
    $(".subconteudo.tres").slideUp();
    $(".subconteudo.quatro").slideUp();
    $(".subconteudo.cinco").slideUp();
    $(".subconteudo.um").slideDown(3000);
});
```

5 more times for each of the classes(um,dois,...). And I'm trying to make a smaller code with 'this' like this:

```
$(".um, .dois, .tres, .quatro, .cinco").click(function () {
    $(".subconteudo.um").slideUp();
    $(".subconteudo.dois").slideUp();
    $(".subconteudo.tres").slideUp();
    $(".subconteudo.quatro").slideUp();
    $(".subconteudo.cinco").slideUp();
    $(this + ".subconteudo").slideDown();
});
```

Is it possible? How?
Thank You
By the way the html code is like this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="submenu um"></div>
    <div class="submenu dois"></div>
    <div class="submenu tres"></div>
    <div class="submenu quatro"></div>
    <div class="submenu cinco"></div>
</div>
<div class="conteudo">
    <div class="subconteudo um"></div>
    <div class="subconteudo dois"></div>
    <div class="subconteudo tres"></div>
    <div class="subconteudo quatro"></div>
    <div class="subconteudo cinco"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not just `$(this).slideDown()`?

Comment: put a common class to all those and do `$('.commonclass').click(function(){$('.subconteudo').slideUp();}) `that way you´ll save like 6 lines.

Comment: @SebastianUrielMurawczik Make that an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution using `filter()` and a simple regex (`/\b(um|dois|tres|quatro|cinco)\b/g`):

```
$(".um, .dois, .tres, .quatro, .cinco").click(function () {
    var firedClass = "."+this.className.match(/\b(um|dois|tres|quatro|cinco)\b/g)[0];
    $(".subconteudo").filter(".um, .dois, .tres, .quatro, .cinco").not(firedClass).slideUp();
    $(".subconteudo").filter(firedClass).slideDown();
});
```

It gets the menu clicked class through a regex. It is necessary because the `menu` could have more than one class of the list `.um, .dois, .tres, .quatro, .cinco` - (if it does, it picks the first found in this order: `.um` -> `.dois` -> `.tres` -> `.quatro` -> `.cinco`, which is intentional).

Also, this will keep the clicked `subconteudo` from sliding up. (Will slide up only the others.)

**[Demo link here.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/x2Vza/3/)**

Comment: I edited the answer. The code behaves the same, but it is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this

```
$(".um, .dois, .tres, .quatro, .cinco").click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('subconteudo')) {
       $(".subconteudo").not(this).slideUp();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('submenu')) {
       $(".submenu").not(this).slideUp();
    }
    $(this).slideDown(3000);
});
```

As all the elements seem to have a common class`subconteundo` , you can always target them excluing the currently clicked element.

Comment: I have to specify which previous class I want to slide up otherwise it doesn't do anything

Comment: Because you do not have a common class occurrence, you can get away be checking for the class on the element that is clicked.. Check edit.. It's a hassle if you have multiple classes , so for each class instance you would require a check condition.. you can get away be using a common class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is! :)

You can only use 4 lines. I've changed a little bit the original HTML code but I think is better now.

JS

```
$(".menu").children().click(function () {
    $(".conteudo").children().slideUp();
    $(".conteudo ."+$(this).attr("class")).slideDown();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="um">MENU 1</div>
    <div class="dois">MENU 2</div>
    <div class="tres">MENU 3</div>
    <div class="quatro">MENU 4</div>
    <div class="cinco">MENU 5</div>
</div>
<div class="conteudo">
    <div class="um">CONTEUDO 1</div>
    <div class="dois">CONTEUDO 2</div>
    <div class="tres">CONTEUDO 3</div>
    <div class="quatro">CONTEUDO 4</div>
    <div class="cinco">CONTEUDO 5</div>
</div>
```

[You can see the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/MBWXv/)

Comment: This is what I was looking for but I need the classes that you retired soo it's easier to me to use the code from acdcjunior.

Answer (score 0):

put a common class to all those and do `$('.commonclass').click(function(){$('.subconteudo').slideUp();})` that way you´ll save like 6 lines.